# What can cause an MFC OpenInventor program to freeze inside nvwgf2umx.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc, openinventor

I am currently facing the hardest bug chase of my young developer career. The software we provide is used only in the company internally having several hundred users / computers, but only on one the software does not work. The problematic program is based on MFC and uses [OpenInventor](https://www.openinventor.com/) for 3D visualisation.

When the user starts the software and creates a new file, internally a new *CDocument* is created connect to a view that uses/displays an *SoWinFullViewer*. The user can see that frame of the MFC view is created but the *SoWinFullViewer* is not displayed. In this state the whole application freezes.

I am unable to reproduce the issue on my developing machine or on any other computer.
For debugging, I deployed an debug build on the problematic computer. But the debug build runs fine. So I deployed a release build with debugging symboles and used the Remote Debugger from Visual Studio. When I start the release build via Remote Debugger everything works fine. If I start the program first on the problematic computer manually, then attach the process via Remote Debugger and then create the new file, the program freezes. After pausing the program, the debugger stands always in a thread of *nvwgf2umx.dll*.

I expected an issue with the GPU driver, so I let the IT reinstalled the GPU drivers. The problem stayed alive. The only option I see right now is to let the IT reinstall the whole system - praying that this will solve the issue.

What can I do for further debugging? What can cause an application to freeze inside *nvwgf2umx.dll* ?

Based on the comment I pulled a dump and analyzed it with WinDbg. This is the result of

*!analyze -v* :

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22000.194 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [S:\_PROJECTS-GL\_DEP_L-D\L-DL\L-DL-FSCC\_Home\zimmde1\_Scratch\lisa (3).DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 19042 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Tue Jan 11 08:45:35.000 2022 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 22:16:14.694
Process Uptime: 0 days 1:39:10.000
................................................................
................................................................
.....
Loading unloaded module list
.
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14:
00007ffe`0c250764 c3              ret
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .sympath+ E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\build\VS2012\Release\binx64
Symbol search path is: srv*;E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\build\VS2012\Release\binx64
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;e:\sandboxes\heliosbuild\build\vs2012\release\binx64

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
OK                                             E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\build\VS2012\Release\binx64
0:000> .sympath+ https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/
Symbol search path is: srv*;E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\build\VS2012\Release\binx64;https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;e:\sandboxes\heliosbuild\build\vs2012\release\binx64;https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
OK                                             E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\build\VS2012\Release\binx64
Deferred                                       https://driver-symbols.nvidia.com/
0:000> .srcpath+ E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\src
Source search path is: E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\src

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
OK                                             E:\Sandboxes\HeliosBuild\src
0:000> ld*
Symbols loaded for nvoglv64
Symbols loaded for sysfer
[...]
Symbols already loaded for ntdll
0:000> .reload
................................................................
................................................................
.....
Loading unloaded module list
.
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for InventorBase.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Inventor.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for InventorGui.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for InventorWin.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for lisa.exe
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for InventorGL.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for lsvdialog.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2078

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 16761

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 4280

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 492749

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 289

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 80174

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 5950

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 1.62.0.0


NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000138

PROCESS_NAME:  lisa.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
0000007f`ecb8aa58 00007ffe`0c1d9205     : 000001b7`f99a8610 000001b7`f9e56f60 00007ffd`d77616c0 00007ffe`09e74f69 : ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
0000007f`ecb8aa60 00007ffe`0c2289bb     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`0c32f3f0 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive+0x165
0000007f`ecb8aad0 00007ffe`0c201276     : 0000007f`ecb8b270 0000007f`ecb8ad80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0x87
0000007f`ecb8ab70 00007ffe`0c250bfe     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00e400ff 00007ffe`0c32f3f0 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x66
0000007f`ecb8ad80 00007ffe`0c2289d7     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000000c 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
0000007f`ecb8b490 00007ffe`0c201276     : 0000007f`ecb8bc30 0000007f`ecb8b740 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f1d32200 : ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0xa3
0000007f`ecb8b530 00007ffe`0c250bfe     : 000001b7`f4a5acd0 00000000`00000000 fe5fffff`ffffffff 000001b7`f4c42430 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x66
0000007f`ecb8b740 00007ffe`0c1b445c     : 00007ffe`0c1db86b 00000000`00730019 00000000`000000c7 000001b7`f996a1e0 : ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
0000007f`ecb8be58 00007ffe`0c1db86b     : 00000000`00730019 00000000`000000c7 000001b7`f996a1e0 0000007f`ecb8c1b0 : ntdll!RtlpLfhFindClearBitAndSet+0x8c
0000007f`ecb8be60 00007ffe`0c1db3c7     : 000001b7`efc40000 00007ffd`00000000 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0x21b
0000007f`ecb8bf20 00000000`6c065e2a     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000008 0000007f`ecb8c4b0 0000007f`ecb80000 : ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+0x9a7
0000007f`ecb8c030 00007ffd`d77063b7     : 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8c2c0 00007ffd`c655a8bc : nvoglv64!DllMain+0xfe7a
0000007f`ecb8c060 00007ffd`cef83c64     : 000001b7`f1bed128 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f99a8610 00007ffd`c656733e : msvcr110!malloc+0x5b
0000007f`ecb8c090 00007ffd`cefbbeb1     : 000001b7`f1bed128 00000000`00000004 0000007f`ecb8c180 ffffffff`ffffffff : InventorBase!safeMalloc+0x44
0000007f`ecb8c0d0 00007ffd`cefbc418     : 00000000`00000013 0000b287`bfaab405 0000007f`ecb8c2c0 000001b7`f99a8610 : InventorBase!SbString::toStdWString+0x91
0000007f`ecb8c160 00007ffd`c695c8a8     : 000001b7`f4c96440 000001b7`f1bed128 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000007 : InventorBase!SbString::toWideChar+0x58
0000007f`ecb8c1c0 00007ffd`c696c458     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f99a8610 00000000`81000b8a : Inventor!SoVRMLWorldInfo::getTypeId+0x187e8
0000007f`ecb8c4c0 00007ffd`c6991aa9     : 00000000`00000013 0000007f`ecb8c6a0 00000000`00000013 000001b7`03c20000 : Inventor!SoContextedObjectCache<SoGLBufferObjectCache>::removeSharedGroupDependency+0x8498
0000007f`ecb8c530 00007ffd`c698eeb0     : 00000000`00000013 00000000`803b0000 000001b7`f99a8610 00007ffd`c658c2cb : Inventor!SoFontServer::getCurrentBBoxCache+0x149
0000007f`ecb8c5f0 00007ffd`c63cfe4c     : 0000007f`ecb8c890 00007ffd`c654e1d2 0000007f`803e0000 0000007f`803e0000 : Inventor!SoFontServer::computeStringBoxInfo+0x490
0000007f`ecb8c750 00007ffd`c681f650     : 00000000`00000001 0000007f`ecb8c890 000001b7`f9b6b828 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoFontServer::computeStringBoxInfo+0x1c
0000007f`ecb8c790 00007ffd`c680ef8d     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f9b6b730 000001b7`efb6b2b0 : Inventor!SoText2::GLRender+0x160
0000007f`ecb8ca20 00007ffd`c6442615     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`efb6b1e0 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`f9b6b730 : Inventor!SoShape::GLRenderP+0x12d
0000007f`ecb8caf0 00007ffd`c671ea52     : 000001b7`f99c7ec0 000001b7`81f900a2 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::traverse+0xb5
0000007f`ecb8cb20 00007ffd`c66cb4fb     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000001b7`f9b97090 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoGroupImpl::GLRender+0x152
0000007f`ecb8cb90 00007ffd`c67e8216     : 000001b7`f9b97090 000001b7`f99c35e0 000001b7`00000002 00000000`00000001 : Inventor!SoCachedGroupImpl::GLRender+0x23b
0000007f`ecb8cc40 00007ffd`c6442615     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`00000007 000001b7`f9b6aff0 000001b7`f9b6aff0 : Inventor!SoSeparator::GLRenderBelowPath+0x106
0000007f`ecb8cc80 00007ffd`c671ea52     : 000001b7`f99c75c0 000001b7`815e0007 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::traverse+0xb5
0000007f`ecb8ccb0 00007ffd`c66cb4fb     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000001b7`f9b97090 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoGroupImpl::GLRender+0x152
0000007f`ecb8cd20 00007ffd`c67e8216     : 000001b7`f9b97090 000001b7`f99c35e0 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : Inventor!SoCachedGroupImpl::GLRender+0x23b
0000007f`ecb8cdd0 00007ffd`c6442615     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`00000007 000001b7`f99c0820 000001b7`f99c0820 : Inventor!SoSeparator::GLRenderBelowPath+0x106
0000007f`ecb8ce10 00007ffd`c671ea52     : 000001b7`f995f9e0 000001b7`815e0007 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::traverse+0xb5
0000007f`ecb8ce40 00007ffd`c66cb4fb     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000001b7`f9b97090 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoGroupImpl::GLRender+0x152
0000007f`ecb8ceb0 00007ffd`c67e8216     : 000001b7`f9b97090 000001b7`f99c35e0 000001b7`00000002 00000000`00000001 : Inventor!SoCachedGroupImpl::GLRender+0x23b
0000007f`ecb8cf60 00007ffd`c6442615     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`000001d2 000001b7`f99be320 000001b7`f99be320 : Inventor!SoSeparator::GLRenderBelowPath+0x106
0000007f`ecb8cfa0 00007ffd`c671ea52     : 000001b7`f9960d00 000001b7`839e01d2 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::traverse+0xb5
0000007f`ecb8cfd0 00007ffd`c66cb4fb     : 0000007f`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoGroupImpl::GLRender+0x152
0000007f`ecb8d040 00007ffd`c67e8216     : 000001b7`f9b97090 00000000`00000000 000001b7`00000000 00000000`00000001 : Inventor!SoCachedGroupImpl::GLRender+0x23b
0000007f`ecb8d0f0 00007ffd`c6442615     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`00000007 000001b7`f99c1e00 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoSeparator::GLRenderBelowPath+0x106
0000007f`ecb8d130 00007ffd`c6471bb2     : 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`815e0007 0000007f`ecb8d198 000001b7`f99c35e0 : Inventor!SoAction::traverse+0xb5
0000007f`ecb8d160 00007ffd`c6441371     : 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoGLRenderAction::beginTraversal+0x472
0000007f`ecb8d1e0 00007ffd`c64716cb     : 00000000`00000001 0000007f`ecb8d348 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::apply+0x181
0000007f`ecb8d290 00007ffd`c69cb08a     : 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`f9abc8e0 000001b7`f9abc8e0 : Inventor!SoGLRenderAction::apply+0x20b
0000007f`ecb8d2e0 00007ffd`c6671ce4     : 0000007f`839e01d2 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9abc8e0 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoLineHighlightRenderAction::apply+0x48a
0000007f`ecb8d390 00007ffd`c6670cdd     : 000001b7`f9bd2350 000001b7`00000000 000001b7`00000000 000001b7`80e60000 : Inventor!SoMultiPassManagerImpl::removeAllTraversalPass+0x274
0000007f`ecb8d460 00007ffd`c644134d     : 000001b7`80e60000 000001b7`f9b4aa70 00000000`80e60000 000001b7`80f00000 : Inventor!SoMultiPassManagerImpl::apply+0x36d
0000007f`ecb8d510 00007ffd`c64716f9     : 00000000`00000001 0000007f`ecb8d678 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9b4aa70 : Inventor!SoAction::apply+0x15d
0000007f`ecb8d5c0 00007ffd`c69cb08a     : 000001b7`f99c1e00 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`f9b4aa70 000001b7`f99c1e00 : Inventor!SoGLRenderAction::apply+0x239
0000007f`ecb8d610 00007ffd`c687abaf     : 000001b7`f99a8610 000001b7`f99c1e00 00000000`80f20000 000001b7`f9abc8e0 : Inventor!SoLineHighlightRenderAction::apply+0x48a
0000007f`ecb8d6c0 00007ffd`c69aea6d     : 000001b7`f999b640 000001b7`f999b640 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f4930550 : Inventor!SoDepthOfField::setParameters+0x154f
0000007f`ecb8d700 00007ffd`dbbdfd57     : 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f999b7c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Inventor!SoSceneManagerImpl::render+0x73d
0000007f`ecb8d870 00007ffd`dbbde0bc     : 000001b7`f99bf420 000001b7`f99bf420 000001b7`f99bf420 0000007f`ecb8d979 : InventorGui!SoGuiViewer::doRendering+0x4e7
0000007f`ecb8d8d0 00007ffd`dbbd98c0     : 000001b7`f9b976f0 000001b7`f9b976f0 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f99bfc00 : InventorGui!SoGuiViewer::actualRedraw+0x62c
0000007f`ecb8d9e0 00007ffd`c9e4e486     : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`00000000 000001b7`f99bf420 000001b7`f99bf420 : InventorGui!SoGuiExaminerViewer::actualRedraw+0x230
0000007f`ecb8dac0 00007ffd`c9e0df50     : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8dc90 00000000`00060a00 : InventorWin!SoWinExaminerViewer::actualRedraw+0x26
0000007f`ecb8daf0 00007ffd`c9e0fee4     : 00000000`3f800000 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8dc90 000001b7`f99bf420 : InventorWin!SoWinRenderArea::redraw+0x210
0000007f`ecb8db60 00007ffd`c9e1ade7     : 000001b7`f99bf420 000001b7`f99bf420 000001b7`f1cee020 00000000`00000000 : InventorWin!SoWinViewer::redraw+0x34
0000007f`ecb8db90 00007ffe`0b4be7e8     : 0000007f`ecb8de20 00007ffe`0c318fe0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : InventorWin!SoWinGLWidget::glxWindowProc+0x217
0000007f`ecb8dd20 00007ffe`0b4be47e     : 000001b7`f994906c 00007ffd`c9e1abd0 00000000`00060a00 00007ffd`00000005 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2f8
0000007f`ecb8deb0 00007ffd`c8f2f1b0     : 000001b7`f9949060 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffff0a39 00000000`ffff0a39 : user32!CallWindowProcW+0x8e
0000007f`ecb8df00 00007ffe`0b4be7e8     : 00000000`00000001 0000007f`ecb8e2b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : opengl32!wglWndProc+0x2a0
0000007f`ecb8df70 00007ffe`0b4be36c     : 0000007f`ecb8e2b0 00007ffd`c8f2ef10 00000000`00060a00 00000000`00000005 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2f8
0000007f`ecb8e100 00007ffe`0b4d0f93     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : user32!DispatchClientMessage+0x9c
0000007f`ecb8e160 00007ffe`0c250ba4     : 00000000`00000229 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8e840 00007ffe`0b4beb26 : user32!_fnDWORD+0x33
0000007f`ecb8e1c0 00007ffe`0a1c1124     : 00007ffe`0b4bdec3 00000000`00000040 00007ffe`0c250ba4 000001b7`efb8a8f0 : ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
0000007f`ecb8e248 00007ffe`0b4bdec3     : 00000000`00000040 00007ffe`0c250ba4 000001b7`efb8a8f0 00000000`00000002 : win32u!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
0000007f`ecb8e250 00007ffe`0b4bcb53     : 00000000`00060a00 00000000`40000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : user32!SendMessageWorker+0x823
0000007f`ecb8e2f0 00007ffe`0b4b9bed     : 00007ffe`0b4b9bb0 00007ffe`0b4ce2b1 000001b7`f03cf780 00000000`00000083 : user32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+0x2c3
0000007f`ecb8e3f0 00007ffe`071cb889     : 00007ffe`0b4b9bb0 00000000`00000047 000001b7`f2010900 00000000`00000047 : user32!RealDefWindowProcA+0x3d
0000007f`ecb8e430 00007ffe`071e2f8e     : 00000000`00060a00 0000007f`ecb8ed40 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8ed40 : uxtheme!_ThemeDefWindowProc+0x609
0000007f`ecb8e610 00007ffe`0b4b9846     : 0000007f`ecb8e7a0 00007ffe`0b4c0d92 000001b7`f99bf420 00000000`00060a00 : uxtheme!ThemeDefWindowProcA+0xe
0000007f`ecb8e650 00007ffd`c9e1b2b3     : 000001b7`f99bf420 00000000`00060a00 00000000`00000047 00000000`007fecb8 : user32!DefWindowProcA+0x76
0000007f`ecb8e6a0 00007ffe`0b4be7e8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : InventorWin!SoWinGLWidget::glxWindowProc+0x6e3
0000007f`ecb8e830 00007ffe`0b4be47e     : 000001b7`f2010900 00007ffd`c9e1abd0 00000000`00060a00 00007ffd`00000047 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2f8
0000007f`ecb8e9c0 00007ffd`c8f2f1b0     : 000001b7`f9949060 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffff0a39 00000000`00000000 : user32!CallWindowProcW+0x8e
0000007f`ecb8ea10 00007ffe`0b4be7e8     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`01650222 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : opengl32!wglWndProc+0x2a0
0000007f`ecb8ea80 00007ffe`0b4be36c     : 00000000`01650222 00007ffd`c8f2ef10 00000000`00060a00 00007ffe`00000047 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x2f8
0000007f`ecb8ec10 00007ffe`0b4d60c0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`0c250ba4 : user32!DispatchClientMessage+0x9c
0000007f`ecb8ec70 00007ffe`0c250ba4     : 00000000`00000000 0000007f`ecb8ed78 00000000`0002001e 000001b7`f03cf780 : user32!_fnINLPWINDOWPOS+0x30

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvoglv64!DllMain+fe7a

MODULE_NAME: nvoglv64

IMAGE_NAME:  nvoglv64.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_nvoglv64.dll!DllMain

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.18.13.5456

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {4c63ad3f-1b0d-6f17-5a1f-34f55bfc2ead}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

This tells me that a breakpoint in *nvoglv64.dll* was hit. The Stack Text shows only external code. What could cause that?

And the result of

*!locks -v* :

```
CritSec ntdll!RtlpProcessHeapsListLock+0 at 00007ffe0c318ce0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +efb402c0 at 000001b7efb402c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    2

CritSec +ef9b02c0 at 000001b7ef9b02c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +efed02c0 at 000001b7efed02c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec shell32!g_lockObject+0 at 00007ffe0aef84a0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +f17902c0 at 000001b7f17902c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +f20102c0 at 000001b7f20102c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +f1d27fe0 at 000001b7f1d27fe0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec ntmarta!gWrkrLock+0 at 00007ffe084cc800
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec ntmarta!gCacheLock+0 at 00007ffe084cc860
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec ntmarta!grgRightsNameCache+3f0 at 00007ffe084cd3b0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec ntmarta!grgRightsNameCache+520 at 00007ffe084cd4e0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +fb2c02c0 at 000001b7fb2c02c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec +fb6f02c0 at 000001b7fb6f02c0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec msvcrt!CrtLock_Setlocale+0 at 00007ffe0beff5b0
LockCount          NOT LOCKED
RecursionCount     0
OwningThread       0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    0

CritSec msvcr110!wcmdln+148 at 00007ffdd7765b10
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          5
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       30b0
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    5
*** Locked

Scanned 16 critical sections
```

*~*kvn*

```
 Call Site
 win32u!NtUserGetMessage+0x14
 user32!GetMessageA+0x46
 InventorGL!SoWindowsPowerEventHandler
 InventorBase!SbThread
 msvcr110!beginthreadex+0x107
 msvcr110!endthreadex+0x192
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 win32u!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x14
 user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x1e
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0x332d
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout+0x81
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddress+0xae
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xfd
 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0x1c4
 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42
 msvcr110!freefls+0xde
 ntdll!RtlpFlsDataCleanup+0x121
 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x48
 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x3e
 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0xc18
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout+0x81
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddress+0xae
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xfd
 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0x1c4
 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42
 msvcr110!freefls+0xde
 ntdll!RtlpFlsDataCleanup+0x121
 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x48
 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x3e
 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0xc18
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0x7d8a
 nvoglv64+0x7b299d
 nvoglv64+0x7b2658
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0xa257
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout+0x81
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddress+0xae
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xfd
 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0x1c4
 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42
 msvcr110!freefls+0xde
 ntdll!RtlpFlsDataCleanup+0x121
 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x48
 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x3e
 KERNELBASE!FreeLibraryAndExitThread+0x4a
 combase!CRpcThreadCache
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout+0x81
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddress+0xae
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xfd
 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0x1c4
 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42
 msvcr110!freefls+0xde
 ntdll!RtlpFlsDataCleanup+0x121
 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x48
 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x3e
 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0xc18
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout+0x81
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnAddress+0xae
 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xfd
 ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0x1c4
 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42
 msvcr110!freefls+0xde
 ntdll!RtlpFlsDataCleanup+0x121
 ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0x48
 ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x3e
 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0xc18
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0x7d8a
 nvoglv64+0x7b299d
 nvoglv64+0x7b2658
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0xa257
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0xe
 nvoglv64!DrvPresentBuffers+0x1f9f6
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
 winmm!timeThread+0x91
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e
 tsprint!CAPCThread
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0x7d8a
 nvoglv64!DrvPresentBuffers+0x1bfe6a
 nvoglv64!DrvValidateVersion+0xa257
 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
 ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive+0x165
 ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0x87
 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x66
 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e (TrapFrame @ 0000007f`edeff3a8)
 msvcr110!_addlocaleref+0x71
 msvcr110!initptd+0xac
 msvcr110!CrtEndBoot+0x140
 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x61
 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x167
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x408
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b
 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 ntdll!LdrpDrainWorkQueue+0x15e
 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x8b
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x408
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b
 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe


 Call Site
 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
 ntdll!LdrpDrainWorkQueue+0x15e
 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x8b
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x408
 ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b
 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

Comment: *"What can I do for further debugging?"* - Pull a dump from application when it's in its "frozen" state. You can use Task Manager to do so. Load the minidump up in a debugger (WinDbg preferably), and set up symbol and source locations. That will show you where (and probably also why) one or more threads in the process aren't making any forward progress.

Comment: @IInspectable added an WinDbg analysis. But this pointed me only to another nvidia dll - or I misunterstand that analysis

Comment: There's a dubious entry in the call stack: `nvoglv64!DllMain+0xfe7a`. It's odd for two reasons: `1` Code in `DllMain` shouldn't attempt to synchronize with other code. `2` The offset is pretty large, so this is probably not really inside `DllMain`. Try getting symbols from the [NVIDIA symbol server](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-driver-symbol-server). The thread appears to be waiting on the shared heap. See if the [!locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-locks---kdext--locks-) command produces any cycles.

Comment: @IInspectable Tried your suggestions but could't get any information out of this (Probably due to my low debug skills in this case). I asked our IT to check the file system and system libraries for sanity, but they said no - Computer to old and not more supported. Therefor I also stopped looking into this. I appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Don't get discouraged, debugging *is* hard. And it will stay that way throughout your career, with the only variance being how quickly you get to the tough parts. If you cannot afford to sink more time into this right now consider pulling a [TTD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) trace for future analysis. It's like a time capsule that will indefinitely preserve the error condition. It'll still be there when you're ready to give it a second (or third) shot. Keep it in a safe place.